# Conditional Binding of Properties using MVVMCross

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

What is the best way to implement the following using mvvmcross binding:

```
if (ViewModel.NumberOfUsers > 1)
  set.Bind (NumberOfUsersLabel).To ("NumberOfUsers + ' Users'");
else
  set.Bind (NumberOfUsersLabel).To ("NumberOfUsers + ' User'");
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, Mvvm developers do this type of formatting in a `ValueConverter`

For more on this, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters

This includes the "time ago" sample which shows how to change the string depending on current value:

```
public class MyTimeAgoValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<DateTime, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(DateTime value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var timeAgo = DateTime.UtcNow - value;
        if (timeAgo.TotalSeconds < 30)
        {
            return "just now";
        }

        if (timeAgo.TotalMinutes < 10)
        {
            return "a few minutes ago";
        }

        if (timeAgo.TotalMinutes < 60)
        {
            return "in the last hour";
        }

        if (timeAgo.TotalMinutes < 24*60)
        {
            return "in the last day";
        }

        return "previously";            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just create a property that has a getter in your view model.

```
public string NumberOfUsersFormatted { get { return NumberOfUsers + " user"; } }
```

Then in your ViewDidLoad:

```
set.bind(NumberOfUsersLabel).To(NumberOfUsersFormatted);
```

Then you can put any additional checks into your view model property.

If you don't like that you could also set up your own ValueConverter that appends the right word.